# CSS Class cannot be applied for EditorFor on ASPX C# view engine

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I have developed a UI using basic html attributes and bootstrap framework. 
Now I want to add `Html.EditorFor()` instead of `<input type="text" class="form-control" />`.

I added it in this way

`<%= Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name,new { @class = "form-control" }) %>`

but my html page cannot render this. It shows a basic html input. Bootstrap class has not been applied on it. But this class attribute is working for `Hrml.TextBoxFor()`

I'm using `ASPX C#` View Engine. Not `RAZOR`.

I went through some stack-overflow questions and answers. According to the most answers, my syntax is correct.

How to apply css classe on `Html.EditorFor()`...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Html.EditorFor takes an additionalViewData object rather than the normal htmlAttributes that you have with TextBoxFor, etc.

All you should need to do is wrap your attributes in an additional object (in the same way as you would in Razor) by changing your call to the following:

```
<%= Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" }}) %>
```